# How to statically typize a big "data objects" in Java?

Tags: java, validation, types, static-analysis

I have a many data objects which is just contain data and not have methods to handle this data. This objects is just containers for my data.

For example object contains post data such as: title, text, tags, keywords, author, date of publish, date of editing, preview image, short description.

As you see, we have 9 properties.

**How to represent such data in Java with compile time checks and minimal boilerplate?**

If i will create class `Post` which will take properties in constructor, then i will hard to create instance, because i will have to remember arguments order and if i will have to 30 properties, it will very ugly and unmaintainable.

If i will create class `PostBuilder` which will construct a post object by call chain methods, then i can got runtime error if i will not fill all required fields for example. Same with setters for initialization.

If i will use `HashMap`, then i can't specify types for each key and its value, i can only specify one type for all keys and for all values and have to validate data in runtime.

On typescript i could write this code:

```js
interface Post {
 title: string;
 text: string;
 tags: string[];
 keywords: string[];
 date: number;
 editDate: number | null;
 // All other props ...
};

const myPost: Post = {
 title: "My title";
 text: "My text";
 tags: ["first post"];
 keywords: [];
 date: new Date().getTime();
 editDate: null;
 // All other values ...
};
```

And if i will not specify some property or will specify value with other type, i will got compile time error.

Comment: You could use [records](https://dev.java/learn/using-record-to-model-immutable-data/).

Comment: @Jesper but what if we have 30 properties? We have to remember order of arguments while create record object, right? Maybe exist some way suitable for the objects which have really many properties?

Comment: If you use an IDE (such as IntelliJ or Eclipse), it will handle automatic creation of various things including getters and setters. If you add 20 more fields to a class, it takes only a few clicks to create new getters and setters for those fields.

Comment: I don't see a way using pure Java.  If you want compile time errors, you might look into creating your own very simple scripting language, and plugging that into the build process.  That way you at least do get a compile time error. (And that idea seems really obtuse now that I type it.  Maybe a better way is to use unit tests, and just test all your object creation code, so that any runtime errors occur as soon as possible.)

Comment: Another option is to use [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org), which can automatically generate a builders, getters, setters, etc.

Comment: I think he want's compile time errors, it's not the difficulty of creating the getters and setters that's the problem. iiuc

Comment: @markspace you're right, i need a compile time validation, but not just builder. I found a https://github.com/immutables/immutables which [promise](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#staged-builder) a validation of builder method calls to ensure that all properties been filled. I will check it out, but i'm worried about generate boilerplate interfaces which may decrease performance. Maybe exists some annotations which will not generate nothing in runtime, but only check builder methods calls on compile time?

Comment: No, no such annotation exists.  Right now I think you're best bet us to use the unit tests.

Comment: @markspace tests it's important, but i use java in my project to catch most errors on compile time, so tests it's not that i need for this case. JVM infrastructure are reach, so i sure, should exist some project which ensure complete built objects on compile time

Comment: I’m confused. How do you expect to perform data validation at compile-time on data that arrives at run-time? That’s a bit like asking for your score on a test you haven’t taken yet.

Comment: @BasilBourque i don't need to validate data at compile time. I need a way to create an object with big number of parameters. And i need to ensure that all parameters will set for object and all parameters have expected type. See my example with typescript where i do it